# php - about mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a question about `mysql_real_escape_string`.

I know that `mysql_real_escape_string` can escape the character such as backslash(\), single quote('), double quote(") and others. My question is:

1. `mysql_real_escape_string` cannot escape the underscore(_), percentage(%) and less than sign(<)?
2. In order to escape them, I need to use double slashes to escape it and save it to the database?
3. What character requires double slashes to escape it?

Comment: *...with prepared statements.* PDO on its own, doesn't do much really. @basic_space *"use PDO instead"*

Comment: You can't use `PDO` or `mysqli`? `Mysql_` functions are deprecated, `This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.` With the new drivers prepared/parameterized queries are supported.

Comment: Use stripslashes  http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: nothing else needs to be escaped.